# ValueError: "needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used"

Tags: python, django

I have created an extended user model that I use on my sign-up page. The two custom models are "Cristin" and a many-to-many field named "Rolle" (the person's role in the organization).

After I added the many-to-many field, I get the following error message: **ValueError at /accounts/signup/ –"Userextended: *username_that_I_registered_with*" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.**

I have googled for three hours now, and it seems that the solution is to use **commit=False** on the User ID before saving the model. However, I'm new to Django and Python and have trouble pinpointing where I should write the code and my attempts has so far been unsuccessful. If you can help me solving this problem, please provide the solution through code as well.

My **models.py** file:

```
class User(auth.models.User,auth.models.PermissionsMixin):
def __str__(self):
    return "@{}".format(self.username)

class Personrolle(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')
    persrolle = models.CharField(max_length = 30, verbose_name="Role")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.persrolle

class Userextended(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cristin = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    rolle = models.ManyToManyField(Personrolle)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

...
```

My **forms.py** file:

```
...

from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from accounts.models import Userextended
from accounts.models import Personrolle
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):

    cristin = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    rolle = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Personrolle.objects.all())

    class Meta():
        fields = ('first_name','last_name','username','email','password1','password2')
        model = User
        labels = {'username': 'Email',
                  'first_name': 'First name',
                  'last_name': 'Last name',
                  'email': 'Confirm email',
                  'password1': 'Password',
                  'password2': 'Confirm password',
                  'cristin': 'Cristin-ID',
                  'rolle': 'Rolle'}

    def save(self, commit=True):
        if not commit:
            raise NotImplementedError("Can't create User and Userextended without database save")
        user = super(UserCreateForm, self).save(commit=True)
        user_profile = Userextended(user=user,cristin=self.cleaned_data['cristin'],rolle=self.cleaned_data['rolle'])
        user_profile.save()
        return user

...
```

**More detailed description of the error**

- Request Method:  POST
- Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/signup/
- Django Version:  1.11.2
- Exception Type:  ValueError
- Exception Value: 
  "Userextended: username_that_I_registered_with" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
- Exception Location:  .../anaconda/envs/myEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py in **init**, line 830
- Python Executable:   .../anaconda/envs/myEnv/bin/python
- Python Version:  3.6.1

**My traceback:**

```
File ".../anaconda/envs/myEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File ".../anaconda/envs/myEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File ".../anaconda/envs/myEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File ".../anaconda/envs/myEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File ".../anaconda/envs/myEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File ".../anaconda/envs/myEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  217.         return super(BaseCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)

File ".../anaconda/envs/myEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  183.             return self.form_valid(form)

File ".../anaconda/envs/myEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in form_valid
  162.         self.object = form.save()

File "…PROJECT/accounts/forms.py" in save
  57.         user_profile = Userextended(user=user,cristin=self.cleaned_data['cristin'],rolle=self.cleaned_data['rolle'])

File ".../anaconda/envs/myEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in __init__
  566.                             _setattr(self, prop, kwargs[prop])

File ".../anaconda/envs/myEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py" in __set__
  536.         manager = self.__get__(instance)

File ".../anaconda/envs/myEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  513.         return self.related_manager_cls(instance)

File ".../anaconda/envs/myEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py" in __init__
  830.                                  (instance, self.pk_field_names[self.source_field_name]))

Exception Type: ValueError at /accounts/signup/
Exception Value: "<Userextended: testytester@yahoo.com>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just need to edit your save method in your form,

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
    if not commit: 
        raise NotImplementedError("Can't create User and Userextended without database save") 
    user = super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    user_profile = Userextended(user=user, cristin=self.cleaned_data['cristin']) 
    user_profile.save() 
    user_profile.rolle.add(self.cleaned_data['rolle'])
    user_profile.save()
    return user
```

You need to save your `UserExtended` model first, then add the `Rolle` instances to the many to many relation.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using DRF you can use the validate method:

instead of this

```
    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data['slug'] = slugify(validated_data['name'])
        return budgets.models.BudgetCategory.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.slug = slugify(validated_data['name'])
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

do this

```
def validate(self, data):
        data['slug'] = slugify(data['name'])
        return data
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message happened because "rolle" should be specified as a many-to-one relationship and not a many-to-many. The model has been updated to the following and is now working perfectly:

```
class Userextended(models.Model):
    ...
    rolle = models.ForeignKey(Personrolle, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
```