# "<Model: ModelInstance>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used

Tags: python, django, rest

Currently getting this error between my UserProfile model and Song model when I try to get all user songs `"song = user_prof.songs.all()"` and error is the title `"<UserProfile: ...>`. This is my first time using a through model for two models (Song and Note) and am suspicious. The `UserProfile`, `Song`, `Notes`, and `SongNotes` instances are all saved and viewable in django admin, however the `song_instance` does not show any notes, in fact it doesnt even show its notes field im guessing due to the through.

**Song View**

```
class Songs(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        try:
            data = self.request.data

            user_song = data['song']
            name = data['name']

            user = self.request.user
            user_prof = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)

            song_instance = Song.objects.create(name=name)

            user_prof.songs.add(song_instance)
            user_prof.save()

            for index, pair in enumerate(user_song):
                note = Note.objects.create(note=pair[0], timestamp=pair[1])
                song_note_through = SongNote.objects.create(song=song_instance, note=note, order=index)

            
            song_instance.save()
            return Response({ 'success': 'Song created' })
        
        except Exception as e:
            print('Songs:post ', e, file=sys.stderr)
            return Response({ 'error': 'Unable to create song' })
    
    def get(self, request, id='all', format=None):
        try:
            if id == 'all':
                user = self.request.user
                user_prof = UserProfile(user=user)
                song = user_prof.songs.all()
            else:
                song = Song.objects.get(id=id)

            serializer = SongSerializer(song)

            return Response({ 'song': serializer.data})
        except Exception as e:
            print('Songs:get ', e, file=sys.stderr)
            return Response({ 'error': 'Unable to get song' })
```

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    posts = models.ManyToManyField('Post', blank=True, related_name='created_post')
    songs = models.ManyToManyField('Song', blank=True)
    
    
class Song(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    notes = models.ManyToManyField('Note', through='SongNote', blank=True)

class Note(models.Model):
    note = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    timestamp = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    
class SongNote(models.Model):
    song = models.ForeignKey(Song, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    note = models.ForeignKey(Note, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order']
```

**traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 80, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 124, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 140, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request)
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 57, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 140, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\corsheaders\middleware.py", line 56, in __call__
    result = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 57, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 140, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 134, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 57, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 140, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 134, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 57, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 140, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 134, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 57, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 140, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 134, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 57, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 140, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 134, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 57, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 140, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 134, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 57, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 140, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 134, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 57, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 140, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 65, in _view_wrapper
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 104, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebsite\sheetmusic\views.py", line 400, in get
    song = user_prof.songs
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 650, in __get__
    return self.related_manager_cls(instance)
  File "C:\Users\19494\Desktop\Coding\Python\SheetMusicWeb\SheetMusicWebvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 1069, in __init__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: "<UserProfile: Yvanna>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

I've looked around for a while. There is another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44804129/valueerror-needs-to-have-a-value-for-field-id-before-this-many-to-many-relat)  with this question however it did not help. Most suggestions are that I am not successfully saving my Song model before accessing its attributes but I can see that they are in the admin panel.

Comment: i believe since you don't have a related_name set in the through model, you should be accessing songs from a user through the default django names. `user.song_set.all()`

Comment: Post full traceback.

Comment: `user_prof = UserProfile(user=user)` won't get you existing data from the database but instead you've created a new object, given you've not called `.save()` on it yet it does not have an id as well. Check the duplicate on how to get the actual related object for one to one fields.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Im embarrassed. Thank you